# Unable to resolve image in web app

Tags: html, css, angular, web-applications, relative-path

I'm trying to insert a background image on an element in an Angular web app I'm working on, but for some reason the relative path for the image breaks my app.

[image]

This is odd, because in my HTML for this component, I have another image that loads just fine using the same relative path (the files are in the same folder)

```
<img src="../../assets/images/img1.jpg">
```

Comment: Use `<img src="../../../assets/images/img1.jpg">` ,  did it solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your path is incorrect just write your path like below:

```
.info {
   background-imgae: url('assets/images/geometry.png')
}
```

and for your other image just write your code like this:

```
<img src="assets/images/img1.ong">
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta go back one more folder:

```
<img src="../../../assets/images/img1.jpg">
```

The way it is, you are inside app folder, and the assets folder is outside.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried this and it works, but why does the relative path work in the HTML and not the CSS?

Comment: @user8972341 Is the html in the same folder as the css? If it is, it should work. Also don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Angular knows about the asset folder so relative path is not required at all